# Regular expression with "not character" not matches as expected

Tags: regex

I am trying to satisfy next restrictions:

1. line has from 3 to 256 chars that are a-z, 0-9, dash - or dot .
2. this line cannot start or end with -

I want to get kind of next output:

```
aaa  -> good
aaaa -> good
-aaa -> bad
aaa- -> bad
---a -> bad
```

A have some of regexes that don't give right answer:
1) `^[^-][a-z0-9\-.]{3,256}[^-]$` gives all test lines as bad;

2) `^[^-]+[a-z0-9\-.]{3,256}[^-]+$` treats first three lines as one matching string since [^-] matches new line I guess.

3) `^[^-]?[a-z0-9\-.]{3,256}[^-]?$` (? for one or zero matching dash) gives all test lines as good

Where is the truth? I'm sensing it's either close to mine or much more complicated.

P.S. I use python 3 re module.

Comment: Negative lookahead/lookbehind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is almost correct: `^[^-][a-z0-9\-.]{3,256}[^-]$`

The `[^-]` at the start and end represent one character already, so you will need to change `{3,256}` into `{1,254}`

Also, you probably only want a-z, 0-9 and . at the start and end (not just *anything* except -), so the full regex becomes:

```
^[a-z0-9.][a-z0-9\-.]{1,254}[a-z0-9.]$
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a lookahead to confirm that the line matches your basic requirement (`(?=^[0-9a-z.-]{3,256}$)`) and then apply further restrictions.:

```
^((?=^[0-9a-z.-]{3,256}$)[^-].*[^-])$
```

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/rQ3aV0/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
^(?!-)[a-z0-9.-]{3,256}(?<!-)$
```

Where `(?!-)` is a negative lookahead assertion (not followed by a dash) and `(?<!-)` is a negative lookbehind (not preceded by a dash).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `{3,256}`... You want `{1,254}` because `[^-]` each also match 1 character at the beginning and end of your string, so you have to subtract them from the total amount of characters that you want.

```
^[a-z0-9.][a-z0-9.-]{1,254}[^a-z0-9.]$
```

Or, if you want to keep your values you can also use lookahead/behinds:

```
^(?=[a-z0-9.])[a-z0-9.-]{3,256}(?<=[a-z0-9.])$
```

Comment: You've got your lookarounds reversed.

Comment: @AlanMoore Corrected. Don't work much with them, always get them confused x-)